# .htacces path to .htpasswd causing internal server error

Tags: php, .htpasswd

So i've tried pretty much every path possible but every time i'm getting an internal server error, maybe i'm overlooking something anyone has an idea?

path to .htacces:  /domains/domain.com/public_html/route/portfolio/inc

path to .htpasswd  /domains/domain.com/public_html/route/portfolio/inc/etc

htacces:

```
AuthUserFile /public_html/route/portfolio/inc/etc
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you mean `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html):

`The AuthUserFile directive sets the name of a textual file containing the list of users and passwords for user authentication. File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.`

In your case the path is treated as absolute, because it starts with /. You must change it to `/domains/domain.com/public_html/route/portfolio/inc/etc` or  `./public_html/route/portfolio/inc/etc`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've read the documentation and tried these paths as well still no luck tho.